# Latest date in SQL with four linked tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I trying to update a PAT testing database which is originally written in access 2003. I am using a HTML styling and activeX connection to get the data from the access database. I am new to coding and basically find most of my answers via google. Currently I am stumped on how to write the SQL query that finds the last test date of appliance. The information in the database is in 4 database tables. (Sorry for the formatting of the tables).

Appliance_Details

```
+-------+------------------+----------+------------+
| PATID | ShortDescription | Location | Department |
+-------+------------------+----------+------------+
| FD110 |                1 | Room 125 |          1 |
| FD113 |                2 | Room 125 |          1 |
| FD114 |                3 | Room 125 |          1 |
+-------+------------------+----------+------------+
```

Appliance_Description

```
+--------+----------------+
| Number | AppDescription |
+--------+----------------+
|      1 | Microwave      |
|      2 | Food Steamer   |
|      3 | Smoothie Maker |
+--------+----------------+
```

Department_List

```
+--------+-------------------+
| Number |   Department      |
+--------+-------------------+
|      1 | Food Technology   |
|      2 | Art               |
|      3 | Humanities        |
+--------+-------------------+
```

Test_Results

```
+-------+---------+----------+
| PATID | AppPass | TestDate |
+-------+---------+----------+
| FD110 | Pass    | 23/04/15 |
| FD110 | Pass    | 04/04/14 |
| FD110 | Pass    | 10/04/13 |
| FD113 | Pass    | 23/04/15 |
| FD113 | Fail    | 04/04/14 |
| FD113 | Pass    | 10/04/13 |
| FD114 | Pass    | 23/04/15 |
| FD114 | Pass    | 04/04/14 |
| FD114 | Pass    | 10/04/13 |
+-------+---------+----------+
```

The SQL query I have so far is:-

```
SELECT l.department, d.PATID AS Appliance, AppDescription As Type, Location, AppPass AS Result, TestDate 
FROM (Department_List AS l INNER JOIN (Appliance_Description AS a INNER JOIN Appliance_Details AS d ON a.Number = d.ShortDescription) ON l.Number = d.Department) INNER JOIN Test_Results AS t
ON d.PATID = t.PATID 
ORDER BY l.department, d.PATID
```

Which gives the results

```
+------------+-------+----------------+----------+--------+----------+
| Department | PATID |      Type      | Location | Result | TestDate |
+------------+-------+----------------+----------+--------+----------+
| Design     | FD110 | Microwave      | Room 125 | Pass   | 23/04/15 |
| Design     | FD110 | Microwave      | Room 125 | Pass   | 04/04/14 |
| Design     | FD110 | Microwave      | Room 125 | Pass   | 10/04/13 |
| Design     | FD113 | Food Steamer   | Room 125 | Pass   | 23/04/15 |
| Design     | FD113 | Food Steamer   | Room 125 | Fail   | 04/04/14 |
| Design     | FD113 | Food Steamer   | Room 125 | Pass   | 10/04/13 |
| Design     | FD114 | Smoothie Maker | Room 125 | Pass   | 23/04/15 |
| Design     | FD114 | Smoothie Maker | Room 125 | Pass   | 04/04/14 |
| Design     | FD114 | Smoothie Maker | Room 125 | Pass   | 10/04/13 |
+------------+-------+----------------+----------+--------+----------+
```

What I want the SQL query to do is return the most recent date. I know I have to use the max function and I have this SQL query, but I am unsure how to join it to the above SQL query statement.

```
SELECT MAX(t.TestDate) AS LastTestDate, t.PATID FROM Test_Results AS t GROUP BY t.PATID
```

This should give me the results as shown below

```
+-------------+---------+------------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| Department  |  PATID  |       Type       |  Location  |  Result  |  LastTestDate   |
+-------------+---------+------------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| Design      |  FD110  |  Microwave       |  Room 125  |  Pass    |  23/04/15       |
| Design      |  FD113  |  Food Steamer    |  Room 125  |  Pass    |  23/04/15       |
| Design      |  FD114  |  Smoothie Maker  |  Room 125  |  Pass    |  23/04/15       |
+-------------+---------+------------------+------------+----------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `MAX` with a `GROUP BY` (see example below).
Adding or removing columns from the SELECT/GROUP BY will allow the MAX to operate at different levels, e.g. last test date in a specific location, etc.

```
SELECT l.department, 
  d.PATID AS Appliance, 
  AppDescription As Type, 
  Location, 
  AppPass AS Result, 
  MAX(t.TestDate) AS LastTestDate 
FROM (Department_List AS l INNER JOIN (Appliance_Description AS a INNER JOIN Appliance_Details AS d ON a.Number = d.ShortDescription) ON l.Number = d.Department) 
INNER JOIN Test_Results AS t ON d.PATID = t.PATID 
GROUP BY l.department, d.PATID, AppDescription, Location, AppPass
ORDER BY l.department, d.PATID
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was trying to do!  I was trying to join my second SELECT query. I might have figured to move the MAX(t.TestDate) to the SELECT, but I would never have figured out that I needed to group all of the items selected. It had stumped me for the last week.